# How to map a json string into object type in sink transformation

Tags: azure-data-factory

Using Azure Data Factory and a data transformation flow. I have a csv that contains a column with a json object string, below an example including the header:

```
"Id","Name","Timestamp","Value","Metadata"
"99c9347ab7c34733a4fe0623e1496ffd","data1","2021-03-18 05:53:00.0000000","0","{""unit"":""%""}"
"99c9347ab7c34733a4fe0623e1496ffd","data1","2021-03-19 05:53:00.0000000","4","{""jobName"":""RecipeB""}"
"99c9347ab7c34733a4fe0623e1496ffd","data1","2021-03-16 02:12:30.0000000","state","{""jobEndState"":""negative""}"
"99c9347ab7c34733a4fe0623e1496ffd","data1","2021-03-19 06:33:00.0000000","23","{""unit"":""kg""}"
```

Want to store the data in a json like this:

```
{
    "id": "99c9347ab7c34733a4fe0623e1496ffd",
    "name": "data1",
    "values": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-03-18 05:53:00.0000000",
            "value": "0",
            "metadata": {
                "unit": "%"
            }
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-03-19 05:53:00.0000000",
            "value": "4",
            "metadata": {
                "jobName": "RecipeB"
            }
        }
       ....
    ]
}
```

The challenge is that metadata has dynamic content, meaning, that it will be always a json object but the content can vary. Therefore I cannot define a schema. Currently the column "metadata" on the sink schema is defined as object, but whenever I run the transformation I run into an exception:

```
Conversion from ArrayType(StructType(StructField(timestamp,StringType,false), 
StructField(value,StringType,false), StructField(metadata,StringType,false)),true) to ArrayType(StructType(StructField(timestamp,StringType,true), 
StructField(value,StringType,true), StructField(metadata,StructType(StructField(,StringType,true)),true)),false) not defined
```

Comment: can you add a few rows to your source data example - your example json output contains an array so it isn't clear what is the transformation you need - @leon's answer has a nested object not an array

Comment: hi @JasonWelch updated it.

Comment: In your JSON output you have multiple values for a given id and name; but in your example CSV input the id values are unique.  So do you need the array of values as output?

Comment: you are right, the IDs should be the same, silly mistake. My issue is that I cannot map the metadata field from the csv to a json sink, because the metadata on the json sink cannot be strictly defined in the schema. We want to output it as json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the output you expected, we need the expression to get the object `Metadata.value`.

Please ref my steps, here's my source:
[image]

Derived column expressions, create a JSON schema to convert the data:

```
@(id=Id,
        name=Name,
        values=@(timestamp=Timestamp,
        value=Value,
        metadata=@(unit=substring(split(Metadata,':')[2], 3, length(split(Metadata,':')[2])-6))))
```

Sink mapping and output data preview:
[image]

[image]

The key is that your `matadata` value is an object and may have different schema and content, may be 'value' or other key. We only can manually build the schema, it doesn't support expression. That's the limit.

We can't achieve that within Data Factory.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you, so in a nutshell I have to know the keys from the json object, otherwise its not possible to use within data factory?

Comment: @Vegi yes, that's right. We need build the json schema and then mapping the data.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any official documentation that I can referr to?

Comment: @Vegi no, there isn't.  These are  based on our experiences.