# azure data flow I cant pass json string to the sink

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using azure data factory to transform data, I have a derived column to process images.

```
iif(isNull(column1_images),
iif(isNull(column2_images),
iif(isNull(images),'N/A',toString(images))
 ,concat(toString(column12_images),' ','(',column2_type,')')),
 concat(toString(column1_images),' ','(',column1_type,')'))
```

when I click on refresh buton I can see the result :
[image]

but when I pass this column to the sink I'M GETTING THIS ERROR :

> Conversion from StringType to ArrayType(StructType(StructField(url,StringType,true)),false) not defined

can you tell me what is the problem please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting because there is no Schema designed for the Sink. Hence, you need to use Derived column expression and create a JSON schema to convert the data. Check [Building schemas using the expression builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column#building-schemas-using-the-expression-builder).

You can also check this similar kind of [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66687600/how-to-map-a-json-string-into-object-type-in-sink-transformation) for your reference.